# How do I add decimal values of each object in core data to come up with a total?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsdecimalnumber

What I'm trying to do is loop through my core data objects and add the price of each item and return that total. My following code keeps crashing and I don't know why. Previously I was using floats but someone suggested I use NSDecimalNumber instead as it's more accurate. So I went about converting my code to use this.

**Code to loop through objects and add price then return total:**

```
+ (NSDecimalNumber *)totalPriceOfItems:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDecimalNumber *totalPrice = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] init];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"BagItem"];

    // Get fetched objects and store in NSArray
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (BagItem *bagItem in fetchedObjects) {

     //   NSDecimalNumber *price = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[bagItem price]];
      //  NSString *price = [[[bagItem price] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
          //                  [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
            //               componentsJoinedByString:@""];
       totalPrice = [totalPrice decimalNumberByAdding:[bagItem price]];

        NSLog(@"total: %@", totalPrice);
    }

    return totalPrice;
}
```

**The error:**

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException', reason: 'NSDecimalNumber overflow exception'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception your getting is because your trying to add two very large numbers and the number of bits required to represent it is too large for NSDecimalNumber.  Your numbers are likely not the problem, it's the way you're declaring the totalPrice variable.

This line should be changed

```
NSDecimalNumber *totalPrice = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] init];
```

to

```
NSDecimalNumber *totalPrice = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
```

NSDecimalNumber is a wrapper around an NSDecimal (itself around NSValue) and doesn't provide a default value for its init method.  If it did what should the value be?  One, Zero, 100000?  It actually defaults to NaN.  In essence your starting value is probably taking up all the available bytes and whenever you add to it then you get the exception.

NSDecimalNumber has mechanisms built in to handle things like overflows and other math errors (division by zero for example).  You can change the default behavior by by providing a new behavior object with the setBehavior method call.

Comment: NSDecimalNumber *totalPrice = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt:0]; Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are getting the overflow, because the range of `NSDecimal` is greater than that of a `float` (it's not as wide as the range of a `double`, though).

Regardless of the reason, rolling your own loop is not the right approach to requesting aggregated results from Core Data: the API lets you ask the database to total up the prices for you, as long as your code provides proper instructions on how to aggregate the data. You should be able to get the total directly from Core Data by passing an aggregate expression, like this:

```
NSExpression *totalPriceExpr = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"
    arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"Price"]]];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"totalPrice"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:totalPriceExpr];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"BagItem"];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

`fetchedObjects` will contain a single item with the count.

Comment: Very helpful. Didn't realise core data was capable of this.